# invalid flag #cgo LDFLAGS break build with go lang

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, cgo, ldflags

I'm new to the go-lang. I want to use go command to build a binary named `cryptogen` (hyperledger/fabric tool). I download the source code from github and type the following command accroding to readme:

```
CGO_CFLAGS=" " GOBIN=/hyperledger/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin go install -tags "" -ldflags "-X github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/cryptogen/metadata.Version=1.0.7" github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/tools/cryptogen
```

On my Mac OS (OS version is 10.13, go-lang version is 1.10) I'm getting the following error:

```
go build github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/miekg/pkcs11: invalid flag in #cgo LDFLAGS: -I/usr/local/share/libtool
```

I thought I missing `libtool`, after installed it, I'm still getting the same error.

What can I do next?

Comment: try to pull the latest fabric version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an FYI, PKCS11 is not really required to use cryptogen.
You can actually use `-tags "nopkcs11"`

Comment: perfect fix ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a recent problem ([Github PR](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11/pull/64)) made in Go 1.9.4 and 1.10 to fix a security ([associated Go commit](https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/867fb18b6d5bc73266b68c9a695558a04e060a8a%5E%21/#F10))

The fix was made 22 days ago, but the library you are using [github.com/hyperledger/fabric](http://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) uses a vendored version of the pkcs11 library.

Personally I would see if installing github.com/miekg/pkcs11 HEAD, and removing the vendor directory solves the issue.  If it works, create an issue for the fabric author to update the vendoered version or remove it altogether.  There is a possibility (depending on the age of the vendored version) that there was already a breaking change made.

Read through the [initial issue](https://github.com/miekg/pkcs11/issues/63) as well.  It appears you can use

```
CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW='-Wl,--no-as-needed' go install
```

as well.

Comment: I remove '/usr/local/share/libtool' from github.com/miekg/pkcs11 HEAD and then build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has been fixed in GO version 1.10 (the release candidates still had this issue). Yesterday, I've got everything compiled after migrating to GO v1.10 (Ubuntu).

See also: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/93836/7/src/cmd/go/internal/work/security.go

Comment: After installing version 1.10, I was then getting the following error: `ltdl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`.  To fix this, ran the following command: `sudo apt-get install libtool`